# How to access the content of custom wordpress postbox in the SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, wordpress-theming

I have a problem with accessing certain data from wordpress in the sql database. 
It's mainly about an additional postbox built into the theme that I use: https://snag.gy/S468WK.jpg 
It is used to add videos by entering a url. I would like to have an insight into the links that have been added to posts and to be able to add content via phpmyadmin if possible. 
I searched the entire base in search of this but I found nothing. this is the example post in the wp_posts section: https://snag.gy/Y2IaHm.jpg This is just a scrap, but the rest does not matter. There is no information about the added link here. But in some place this should be available, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's stored in the `wp_postmeta` table. Do the search by ID of the post, find all meta for the specific post and figure out what's the key for the data you need. After that, you can retrieve it like so: `get_post_meta('post_id here', 'meta key here', true)`

Comment: Oh thanks, those urls are coded like this 'tvSzs9ZD971351' and that confused me. I probably can not decode it, it seems complicated.